# Trying to make a 3 layer curd tart

Tags: tart

Want to make a 3-layer curd tart or pie using layers of blood orange, lime and lemon curd but don't know how to do it. Do I need to heat all three curds, let all three cool, then pour into pie shell one at a time? Will they bleed together or stay in separate layers?

Answer (score 5):

Cook one layer, pour it into the shell, and chill until firm. When it's firm, cook and add the second layer. You don't want to add the curd while it's still super hot. Let it cool a bit, but pour it before it begins to set. Repeat with the third layer.

That procedure should give you very clean and lasting layers.